# jQuery Plugin - only working on the first load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have modified the [JQUERY BEFORE/AFTER PLUGIN by Catch My Fame](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/25/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/) (jQuery-plugin) and included it in a site I'm busy with.

While the animation & draggable function was working by fine itself ([see here](http://bodyscan.gmodesignz.com/)). After I included it in the project-page it now only works on the initial load.

Once I reload the page the animation isn't working & I cannot drag anything anymore (had it at a point that it worked every 2nd or 3rd reload...but even that's gone now).

What am I missing here?

I tried with Chrome and Firefox. On both browsers it doesn't work (not draggable) when I reload the page.

Comment: what is the plugin name and what does it do?

Comment: The thing with stackoverflow is that we should be able to answer your question without having to click any links. Just a recommendation. Some people will downvote because of that.

Comment: It's working all the time for me...

Comment: Gmo, is the Tooltip plugin problem? I see that menu popup, but only in old IE9.

Comment: Maybe you could post some code of where you are including the plugin and how the page is loaded.

Comment: @The Gmo - You're going to have to be more specific.  The question as it's posed is likely to be closed.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Bear with me...just going to edit the question now. ;-)

Thanks especially to @Grimbode for clarifying how questions should be asked here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is written using server side language (php). The document is creating partial/postbacks which is breaking the context of the JS file. I've seen this same effect in asp.net.  You need to wrap your JS in `document.ready()` or rebind the js by creating a `pageload` function that re-initalizes the js